# Qt start function in different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

This is my GUI class:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_CallEndlessLoop_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    void myEndlessLoopFunc();

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);
};
```

As I have to use the GUI, I want to start myEndlessLoopFunc() in different thread when pushButton CallEndlessLoop is clicked.

This is what I did the function:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_CallEndlessLoop_clicked()
{
  QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(myEndlessLoopFunc());  
}
```

The compiler gives me the message "invalid use of void expression". I included "QtConcurrent". I don't know what I'm doing wrong or maybe I have to do in a different way.

Any help is appreciated....Thanks in advance.

Comment: `QtConcurrent::run(myEndlessLoopFunc());` try removing the `()`.

Comment: Tried and unfortunately not working. The compiler gives the "invalid use of non-static member function" message.

Comment: Perhaps try submitting that error text to your nearest google kiosk. Or failing that, ask about it *here*. Or how abiut this novel idea:[read the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html). Maybe  it says something about member functions, who knows?

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I'm already read this before coming here to ask. And I couldn't find my answer in the doc. Now I'm googling the error message. So far with not much success.

Comment: Sorry about that. You probably isn't familiar with the difference between "(pointer to) function" and "(pointer to) member function". Despite some similarities they are very different. You may want to read about them in [C++ FAQ Lite](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not undestent source of problem. You are missing `this` argument in invocation:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_CallEndlessLoop_clicked()
{
  QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MainWindow::myEndlessLoopFunc);  
}
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html#using-member-functions
all methods have not explicit argument which you have to pass to `QtConcurrent::run` function.

Comment: You're right, I don't understand. I tried yours  but it creates lots of error messages starting with <br>   "no matching function for call to 'run(void(MainWindow::*)(), MainWindow*)' "

Comment: Now that you swapped 'this' and '&MainWindow::myEndlessLoopFunc" , I was able to compile. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've noticed that it has an example in documentation where `this` goes first (I've provided also a link).